How can I define a SwiftData modelContainer in an "AppDelegate" rather than an "App"?
I have a working project using SwiftData that is entirely built with UIViews. Essentially, the user will tap an answer on a UIView, and add a row to my SwiftData output. This works as expected. I would like to port this data over to a new project where I've added AR functionality, and tapping ImageAnchors in the environment opens up the existing views. I am having trouble figuring out how to define the modelContainer in this new project. There is no UIViewController in my original app, but there is one in my new AR app, which further complicates things for me.
For my existing project's "App", I have:
App:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct QuizTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            QuizView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: SwiftDataController.self)
    }
}

Note that the line ".modelContainer(for: SwiftDataController.self) is what I'm essentially trying to set in an AppDelegate.
Model: "SwiftDataController"
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class SwiftDataController: Identifiable {
    
    var module: Int
    var correct: Bool
    var dateTaken: Date
    
    init(module: Int, correct: Bool, dateTaken: Date = .now) {
        self.module = module
        self.correct = correct
        self.dateTaken = .now
    }
}

The data is added via an addItem method in a UIView, and then displayed in a List in a separate view I can access from a button.
Here is my new project's AppDelegate:
import UIKit
import SwiftData

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

I am relatively new to Swift, so any guidance on how to handle this or bypass this blocker would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!
I'm unsure if I can have an App and an AppDelegate in the same project, but I have tried some other ways Google has suggested of declaring the modelContainer in the AppDelegate, and my project crashes when I run it.

Maybe use a singleton or follow this article

I like to isolate the SwiftData code into a "manager".
Here is how to create a container for my model Station.
public struct SwiftDataManager {
    
    public static let instance = SwiftDataManager()
    
    public var container: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
        
        let configuration = ModelConfiguration(for: Station.self,
                                               isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        
        let schema = Schema([Station.self])
        
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(for: schema,
                                           configurations: [configuration])
        } catch {

etc.

TL;DR: don’t do that.
It looks like you're trying to mix the new best practice architecture of having App, Scenes, and Views with the old-fashioned App/AppDelegate architecture. It's possible to do that but it's messy and confusing. Is your original project really using UIView? Or is it written in SwiftUI, using its View class?
I suggest you skip the AppDelegate implementation, build the app entirely in SwiftUI (because Swift Data expects SwiftUI), and follow @gene-de-lisa's suggestion of isolating the Swift Data code to a manager. With iOS version 14, we saw the introduction of the App protocol and the move away from using application delegates. Code samples that use app delegates are quite old at this point, and although they may still be useful examples, you should not be using application delegates in new code.
I say this specifically because you say you're new to Swift and because this looks like greenfield development.
Swift Data plays quite well with SwiftUI, and there's no reason I can see to have anything to do with UIKit or AppDelegate in your project.

this does not help, when you need to use AppDelegate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259457/ea-showbluetoothaccessorypicker-not-showing-in-swiftui
